# Class of matrices for wich $A^T=J-A.$

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, a symmetric matrix is a square matrix that is equal to its transpose. Formally, matrix $A$ is *symmetric* if
$$A = A^{\top}.$$
Instead, a matrix of ones or all-ones matrix is a matrix where every element is equal to one. We denote it with letter $J$. Let $A$ and $J$ both $n\times n$ matrices. Then, are the following relation
$$A^T=J-A.$$
a well known property for certain class of matrices? Is it used in some fields of mathematics?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: $A=\frac12J+B$ with $B$ antisymmetric.

Comment: This condition just fixes the [symmetric part](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SymmetricPart.html) of a matrix to $A_S:=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)=\frac{1}{2}J$. It implies weaker condition like $\mathrm{tr}(A)=\frac{n}{2}$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. And for "antisymmetric part" can we say something?

Comment: @Lely $B$ can be any antisymmetric matrix